# Unity Game Engine : nested prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, prefab

i am learing unity game development from a online course and am facing a problem .
In the course the instructor drags and drops CheckPoints prefab(parent) to prefab folder and in the prefab folder it shows like this[instructors window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9HYF.png)

but when i do the same thing unity only makes prefab of the parent object it dosen't show child objects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOkwB.png)

help ! thanks in advance

by dragging and dropping the CheckPoints gameobject i expected that in prefab folder i would see just like in the hierarchy

sorry for my bad english

Comment: you arent comparing the same windows - yours is of your game heirachy - his is of the project available assets